# Is AM29F040B CMOS EEPROM TTL Compatible

Tags: datasheet, cmos, ttl, eeprom

I can't really make any sense of the datasheet regarding whether the AM29F040B EEPROM can be used with TTL inputs, so wanted to ask on here.

It is a 5V CMOS IC, but there are mentions in the datasheet on page 20 ([AM29F040B Datasheet](http://instrumentation.obs.carnegiescience.edu/ccd/parts/AM29F040B.pdf)). There are two tables showing TTL/NMOS compatibility and CMOS compatibility, but they don't mention different part number which I do not understand. Other EEPROM ICs that I have worked with (like the AT28C64B make it obvious it is TTL compatible and show one table with the pin min and max voltage ranges. How should I interpret a datasheet like this, and is this EEPROM TTL compatible?

The address lines and the I/O lines of this EEPROM will be driven/read from TTL IC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly odd to have two tables for DC characteristics, but note that most of the entries are the same in both. I suspect that they did this to show that the part meets the requirements of both kinds of interface, expressed in terms that are conventionally used to describe each one.

Bottom line is yes, it's TTL-compatible.